# JavaScript popup message on database changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how to make a JavaScript popup message (display for 5 seconds) when a database input for specific users have changed? Kind of like the Xbox live achievement message that comes up each time you do a specific task, but i want mine to check if the level for a specific user changes and then have a popup message saying "Congratulations on reaching level x". I'm going to have a popup message for other things than just level as well so it would need to be easy to design.

I couldn't find anything online so if any of you have any suggestions, please leave me some links.

Comment: Have a look at websockets.

Comment: You either do changes in client-side  or server-side, you could do that easily by sending a message to client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either use a timer and ask via ajax in an interval for new popups

or use websockets/websocketserver to push that info to the client

Comment: Or longpoling request

Comment: their is now way longpolling is a good solution for anything... its waste of ressources and the most ugly way to solve something like that... only a acceptable setup is with event driven server like nginx or mpm-event apache